# how intel cpu support task switch ? Is there a hardware timer which controls?

Tags: switch-statement, task, cpu

I am wondering why the cpu can control the task swith . Except the JMP call and interrupt and excetipn handler , is there a hardware timer that control the cpu switch to another task and excute it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the platform that you're running on.

For example, Linux 2.2 (the last kernel I did any work on) on the PC-type devices, programs a PIT (programmable interrupt timer) so that there's an interrupt delivered on a 100-Hz frequency.

That's 100 times a second or every 10 milliseconds. This is called the tick.

So, every tick, an interrupt service routine within the kernel is called and that ISR is responsible for various things, including pre-empting the currently running task if it has used its entire quanta of time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And is the pit in the processor ?

Comment: I don't think so. It was originally a separate chip long ago (Intel 8253, showing my age there), now it's part of the southbridge chip, I think. Wikipedia has a half-decent picture of the different motherboard components on the southbridge page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing).

Comment: Thank you . For Windows or Linux os , first the pit or other timer cause cpu interrupt and os then deal with the interrutp and execute some code to do task schedual . Are things like that?

Comment: Well, that's how Linux did it (and may still). I've not seen the internals of windows but I imagine it would be wasteful for them to *not* use those facilities.

Comment: Thanks . How do you know Linux uses the faclities? by look up the codes?or some books?

Comment: @cn-deng, I actually did some in-house work on that kernel for a process monitoring/charge-back application a certain large company made. That was where I earned my Linux street cred, such as it is. Turned out to never be released as we found an easier solution. Well, easier than trying to get a kernel patch past Linus :-)

Comment: thank you so much . I have not expected your next comment .OS is my hobby

Comment: @cn-deng, it only took me nine months to respond, that's not *too* bad :-)

Comment: Thank you so much.I am still researching OS, I am still a hobbyer.